# Correct way to interpret this sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, interpretation

> In addition, figure in the $1580 a year your cash investment would have been making had you left the money in a conservative investment like a government bond.

Which way is nicer to parse this sentence to translate into other language?

1. In addition, (figure in) (the $1580 a year) *(that)* your cash investment would have been making / had you left the money in a conservative investment like a government bond.
2. My teacher said another way is rather correct.

(Sorry but I forgot my teacher's answer)

So, is there a nicer way to syntax-parse (interpret) this sentence for understanding meaning of this sentence?

Comment: I don't get the "*figure in the $1580*" but the rest possibly reads as "*Had you left the money in a conservative investment like a government bond, your cash investment would have been making $1580 a year.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence structure is:

- Introductory phrase: "in addition"
- Verb: "figure in"
- Object: "the $1580 a year"

  - Relative clause (part of the object): "[that] your cash investment would have been making had you left the money in a conservative investment like a government bond".

So the reasoning expressed in the sentence is as follows:

> If you had left the money in a conservative investment like a government bond, your cash investment would have been making $1580 a year. Figure in this financial benefit.